# Null checking in LINQ Expression for SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, expression, automapper

I have been tasked with creating LINQ expressions for Automapper, which must be able to be turned into an SQL expression. This means no method calls, which is where I am having problems.

I have a record with two columns of interest - `ProposedStartDate` and `ActualStartDate`. I want to get the `ActualStartDate` if it exists, if null then get the `ProposedStartDate`.

```
     .ForMember(d => d.StartDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => (from foo in s.foo
                                                           orderby foo.ProposedStartDate ascending
                                                           select foo.ProposedStartDate).LastOrDefault()))
```

So far I'm there, but unsure how I can check for nulls and pull the `ActualStartDate` in a safe way. Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the `??` operator. It gets translated into COALESCE on the sql side

```
.ForMember(d => d.StartDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => (from foo in s.foo
                                                      orderby foo.ActualStartDate??foo.ProposedStartDate ascending
                                                      select foo.ActualStartDate??foo.ProposedStartDate).LastOrDefault()))
```

Comment: Well thats easy! I assumed ?? and ? : operations would not work.